# So whats the verdict on NestedScrollView and Recyclerview used together?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-nestedscrollview

It drives me crazy to the point where I am literally compelled to begin pulling my hair (luckily I am bald) when I try to wrap around my brain around the logic Google uses in their developer community support.
I mean one would expect that the widget NSV which google is  advocating indirectly as their root containers , would work with the other almost universally used widget recyclerview.

How didn't this cross their mind is beyond me. And how google still haven't addressed the issues between them both after API22 is baffling us well.

I apologize for the time wasting non productive rant.

**What I have** 
 I guess nothign would be new here since almost everyone struggling with flings inside nestedscrollview has got the same setup as do I. However for completion sake , this is the scaffold of my view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            >


                <View
                    ></View>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@id/tool_bar"
                     />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**The problem**
SIMPLE ! . THE RV should WAI . It should fling when flung and halt when halted. Under the viel of NSV though the RV doesn't fling rather it stops as soon as the finger is lifted up .

**Speculations** 
Which such a short time at my disposal (the clients are always such) and possibly brutal technicality involved between the recyclerview and nsv during scroll, I really was not motivated much to take a candle and walk into the shadows underneath.

I however ran out of options and control+clicked RV. Some people say this issue has something to do with the layout managers.

I will post here if I hopefully come up with a solution. Please post your thoughts here if you have any on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are facing the problem because you are using RV in NSV.

Just use RV as -

```
.......

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="100dp" />
                        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                        </LinearLayout>
```

Use app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in RV may solve your problem.

Comment: There is a slight problem I'll come across if I use this. The TV and RV inside the LinearLayout will not scroll up within its container. That is actually a requirement as per the design. There exists some space between the textview and the bottom of the NSV . Upon dragging that space would be filled up and the RV should start its scroll.

Comment: If you move app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in LinearLayout than. TextView will move till your Toolbar hide and remain visible on top...and RV will work normal scroll. But if you want Textview should also hide on RV scroll than make Textview part of the RV.

Comment: This appears to be a ressonable suggestion. Give me a short while to test this out.

Comment: Partly. I actually have to use NSV no matter what. I have maybe 5 views in the NSV container one of them which is the RV. What I can do is that take your advice and make all the other views part of the RV. This will be a cumbersome job to to do. Also adapter changes would be necessary. I am still waiting for some other suggestions here. If I dont get em I will tag this as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same fling issue with recyclerview.
Set this value to falsev(i don't know the exact method name)

RV.setHasFixedSize(false)

Comment: recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false); I tried this as you suggested. Worked it did not . :|

Comment: have you added nestedScrollingEnabled = true?

Comment: nestedscrollingenabled is a very poor approach. It loads the complete dataset in the RV and kills recycling. If i have a thousand rows in the dataset , it wouldload all of them. This would also cause issue with endless scroll. Unfortunately its not an option